# Angularjs multiple $http.get request

Tags: http, angularjs, get

I need to do two `$http.get` call and I need to send returned response data to my service for doing further calculation.

I want to do something like below:

```
function productCalculationCtrl($scope, $http, MyService){
    $scope.calculate = function(query){

            $http.get('FIRSTRESTURL', {cache: false}).success(function(data){
                $scope.product_list_1 = data;
            });

            $http.get('SECONDRESTURL', {'cache': false}).success(function(data){
                $scope.product_list_2 = data;
            });
            $scope.results = MyService.doCalculation($scope.product_list_1, $scope.product_list_2);
        }
    }
```

In my markup I am calling it like

```
<button class="btn" ng-click="calculate(query)">Calculate</button>
```

As `$http.get` is asynchronous, I am not getting the data when passing in `doCalculation` method.

Any idea how can I implement multiple `$http.get` request and work like above implementation to pass both the response data into service?

Comment: I think you can chain promises

Answer (score 78, accepted):

What you need is `$q.all`.

Add `$q` to controller's dependencies, then try:

```
$scope.product_list_1 = $http.get('FIRSTRESTURL', {cache: false});
$scope.product_list_2 = $http.get('SECONDRESTURL', {'cache': false});

$q.all([$scope.product_list_1, $scope.product_list_2]).then(function(values) {
    $scope.results = MyService.doCalculation(values[0], values[1]);
});
```

Comment: I was going for nesting the promises but your solution is much better.

Comment: @jaux console.log($scope.product_list_1) should return the API response right?Getting "undefined". any clue?

Comment: @jaux, I just figured it out and you updated it :) Thanks for your effort!

Comment: How would you get the headers with this method?

Comment: I get "ReferenceError: q$ is not defined", altho I have $q passed in my service (ex: function(AnotherSvc, $http, $q) ...) ... any clues why?

Comment: @guiomie Is "q$" a typo?

Comment: Yes, I guess I was sleepy by then. Thanks for the help !

Comment: after succeed the response using with that response how can i make again $http request to the server

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple and hacky way: Call the calculation in both callbacks. The first invocation (whichever comes first) sees incomplete data. It should do nothing but quickly exit. The second invocation sees both product lists and does the job.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently so I'm going to post my answer also:

In your case you only have two calculations and it seems to be the case this number is not mutable.

But hey, this could be any case with two or more requests being triggered at once.

So, considering two or more cases, this is how I would implement:

```
var requests = [];
requests.push($http.get('FIRSTRESTURL', {'cache': false}));
requests.push($http.get('SECONDRESTURL', {'cache': false}));

$q.all(requests).then(function (responses) {
  var values = [];
  for (var x in responses) {
    responses[x].success(function(data){
      values.push(data);
    });
  }
  $scope.results = MyService.doCalculation(values);
});
```

Which, in this case, would force doCalculation to accept an array instead.