# Angularjs not rendering $rootscope data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am stuck on some problems , actually I was in problem solved , the problem was header which is not enableing to get response (like CORS issue) ,overcome by using header and transformRequest as shown in below code. After that I got webservice data but in one controller used $rootscope which render some of id of data of second method (API) to use in another controller to put on third one api to get data and I am getting this for only a minute then it will throw error : Cannot read property 'companies data' of null which is field in third api. when I used $rootScope.Test.companies[0].companyname which is store data, and unique for all api like primary key.

```
   var request = $http({
        method: "post",
        url: "http://app.xyz/xyzapp/public/user/login",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        transformRequest: function(obj) {
          var str = [];

          str.push(encodeURIComponent('email_id') + "=" + encodeURIComponent('demo@xyz.com'));
          str.push(encodeURIComponent('password') + "=" + encodeURIComponent('demo@xyz'));
          return str.join("&");
        },            

    });  

    request.success(function( response ) {

        console.log("Hiiiii::::"+JSON.stringify(response,status));
        if (response.status=="success"){


          $rootScope.Test1=response.user_id;

          var request1 = $http({
              method: "post",
              url: "http://app.xyz/xyzapp/public/company/getUserCompanyList",
              headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
              transformRequest: function(obj) {
                var str = [];

                str.push(encodeURIComponent('user_id') + "=" + encodeURIComponent(response.user_id ));
                // str.push(encodeURIComponent('password') + "=" + encodeURIComponent('demo@123'));
                return str.join("&");
              }           

          });  
// getCompany
          request1.success(function( response ) {

              console.log("Hiiiii::::"+JSON.stringify(response,status)+"   "+response.companies.length+":Length");
              if (response.status=="success"){
                // alert(1);
                $state.go('tabdash');
                $rootScope.Test = response;


              }            
          });
```

So please tell me how to use one controller data to another where I am using another api which will get $rootscope date of parent.
Please let me know if anybody know about that or anything

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use variables of one controller inside another controller using two methods

1. Create Service to communicate between them.
2. Use $rootScope.$broadcast

sample code

```
angular.module('myservice', []).service('msgBus', function() {
        this.serviceValue= {};

    }]);
});
```

and use it in controller like this:

controller 1

```
angular.module('myservice', []).controller('ctrl1',function($scope, msgBus) {
    $scope.sendmsg = function() {
        msgBus.serviceValue='Hello'; 
   }
});
```

controller 2

```
angular.module('myservice', []).controller('ctrl2',function($scope, msgBus) {
$scope.checkValue(){   
alert( msgBus.serviceValue);
}
});
```

Comment: if I have nested $http and I want to return nested one data to controller , so what I would do? Please tell me.

Comment: What you need is `$q.all`. refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027196/angularjs-multiple-http-get-request/17027441#17027441

Comment: $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api-one-url', data:{email: email,pwd:pwd }).then(function(apiOneData){
 $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api-two-url', data:{userid:userid}}).then(function(apiTwoData){ // I want to save response in array to use in more than one controller
  console.log(apiOneData, apiTwoData);
 });
});

Comment: @shivam If you got help from this code upvote the answer and click the right icon on the answer

Comment: Can you solve my another issue? -->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408810/angularjs-material-or-angularjs-store-multiple-select-dropdown-data-in-webservic

Comment: I will try my level best