# Angularjs material or angularjs store multiple select dropdown data in webservice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

I am using Angular material and I am stuck on multi selection dropdown , where I was selecting more than one options and on ng-change I am calling function which will get id of every option and I will compare API id but As I select it will provide data in function like 
In first option selection 
123456
In second option selection 
123456,456231

In Third option selection 
123456,456231,471258

so whenever I do compare It goes inside the condition only once and not more even I tried to split It gives error and do nothing.

```
<md-select ng-model="$parent.follower" placeholder="Select Person" multiple="true" ng-change="getFollowers(follower)">             
     <md-option ng-repeat="follower in followers" value="{{follower.id}}"> {{follower.full_name}}</md-option>
   </md-select>
```

So Let me know how to handle this situation, if anyone have experience and very well Please let me know.

Thanks
Shivam

Comment: Can you provide plunker or fiddle, so that problem could be easily understandable

Comment: ng-change call function and that function provide id of option suppose I select apple , It will provide 123 id then I select second option then console show 123,456 same as follow for rest of all.

Comment: ok so if you are getting ids in array then next what you want to do?

Comment: ok let me give pure angularjs multiple selection that can be post on webservice ,Please

Comment: No , not in array simple like 123,4565 if I select single option then 123 , and again select two option then 1223,456 in function

Comment: which means if your ng-change is not getting called on multi selection,Frankly I am not getting your problem

Comment: Ok forget all, can I have example of multiple selection and then store them all to webservice ?

Comment: Ya sure I will give you answer as a example of multiselect and post the values of selected Ids through $http.post()

Answer (score 1):

I have created Codepen for you where you can see the value changing each time
As I dont know you data format I used a demo one

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" class="md-padding selectdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div>
    <h1 class="md-title">Enter an address</h1>
    <div layout="row">
      <md-input-container>
        <label>Street Name</label>
        <input type="text">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>City</label>
        <input type="text">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-select placeholder="State" ng-model="ctrl.userState" multiple="true" ng-change='changeValue(ctrl.userState)'>
        <md-option ng-repeat="state in ctrl.states" value="{{state.abbrev}}">{{state.abbrev}}</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Angularjs Code

```
      'use strict';
      angular
          .module('MyApp')
          .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
            this.userState = '';
            this.states = ('AL AK AZ AR CA CO CT DE FL GA HI ID IL IN IA KS KY LA ME MD MA MI MN MS ' +
                'MO MT NE NV NH NJ NM NY NC ND OH OK OR PA RI SC SD TN TX UT VT VA WA WV WI ' +
                'WY').split(' ').map(function (state) { return { abbrev: state }; });
     $scope.changeValue=function(value){
        console.log(value);
     $http.post(//url).then(function(response){
//handle response here
     });
  }    
  });
```

Codepen for working solution
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvygLZ

Comment: ok , suppose I want to store data in webservice like-- "followers":[{"id":"123","name":"John Sina"}] so how to send them , I am trying like data :{ followers[id ]== data  } but not working

Comment: followers[0].id === data will solve your problem because object is inside array

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/json/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_objectarray_4 take a look here , suppose I want to add one or more first and last name so using $http how would I store , usually I used  format like data:{field_name : datasss} but as I mentioned above comment for  (followers":[{"id":"123","name":"John Sina"}] ) , so for that do you have sysntax to stor data, Please let me know.

Comment: every time store , It will run correct     
 
followers[0].id ===data ?

Comment: You can send complete array and you can check like aangular.forEach(followers,function(follower){ if(follower.id===data){//value}  });

Comment: Hi , As I was considering that the field where I have to send data is array and the data which is going to be send also array , so How  would I store that.

Comment: you can use object to store any find of data .It totally depends on you how you have decided to store your data